# I dont understand what is wrong with this line

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
stockxx["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(stockxx.Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
stockxx.index=stockxx['Date']

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(stockxx["Close/Last"], label= 'Close Price History')
```

I get this

```
File "<ipython-input-13-e522099fd646>", line 2
    stockxx.index=stockxx['Date']
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of line 1.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis "`)`" at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, you are missing a `)`

This

```
stockxx["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(stockxx.Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

should be

```
stockxx["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(stockxx.Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

with the `)` at the end.